# How to create a keyspace in cassandra using gocql

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

Is there any way to create a new keyspace in cassandra with gocql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think there is any specific command in the library, but they create keyspaces as part of the tests (copied below) by issuing a normal query with the  CREATE KEYSPACE command - https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateKeyspace.html

```
func createKeyspace(tb testing.TB, cluster *ClusterConfig, keyspace string) {
    c := *cluster
    c.Keyspace = "system"
    c.Timeout = 20 * time.Second
    session, err := c.CreateSession()
    if err != nil {
        tb.Fatal("createSession:", err)
    }

    err = session.control.query(`DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS ` + keyspace).Close()
    if err != nil {
        tb.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = session.control.query(fmt.Sprintf(`CREATE KEYSPACE %s
    WITH replication = {
        'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
        'replication_factor' : %d
    }`, keyspace, *flagRF)).Close()

    if err != nil {
        tb.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

See here for issue and link to source in tests - https://github.com/gocql/gocql/issues/566

Comment: How can I create a session that has the `control` property in it ?

Comment: session, err := cluster.CreateSession() should do it, but im not sure you need the .Control property, example here just has query method on session - https://github.com/gocql/gocql#important-default-keyspace-changes

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to execute `CREARE KEYSPACE ....` with `session.Query`?  Keyspace creation is just another CQL statement...

Comment: Tried it, but how to create a session to run that ?

Comment: The same way as described in documentation: `cluster := gocql.NewCluster("..."); session, err := cluster.CreateSession();`